# Windows Azure SDK not found by Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2012

### Following the Windows Azure tutorial for deploying an ASP.NET MVC app. http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/

ALSO NOTE: The following is a version of this question with images. https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3ZcV.jpg. I think the images help make the question much clearer. However, as I do not have more than 10 reputation points, I am unable to add more than 2 links or display images.

---

---

How do I get Visual Studio 2012 to find the Windows Azure SDK that I installed? A similar question was asked on stackoverflow (titled unable-to-create-windows-azure-project-in-visual-studio-2012), but the suggested solution was a total reinstallation of Visual Studio. Is there a faster and less invasive solution? Or on the other hand, why does VS 2012 and Windows Azure screw up installation so much (this is not the first time I've been prompted to reinstall everything)?

I am following the Windows Azure tutorial for deploying a ASP.NET MVC app. In the "Set up the development environment" section, the tutorial prompts the user to install the Windows Azure SDK. I installed the Windows Azure SDK.

Continuing with the tutorial, in step 7a of the tutorial, I am instructed to "Add Windows Azure subscription." However, when I click the "Add Windows Azure subscription" link, I am notified that there is a "Missing Component" because the Windows Azure SDK for .NET cannot be found.

How do I fix this issue without uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio 2012 and Windows Azure SDK all over again (as suggested in the stack overflow link above).

Comment: I'm tempted to uninstall everything now, but I'll hold off for a little while in the hopes that someone will read this and come up with a viable solution.

Comment: In the meantime, I've worked around this, pushing to GitHub, and deploying the site by linking to the GitHub repository. Hopefully this issue can be resolved though, in case other people have similar questions in the future.

Comment: Have you tried just re-installing the SDK?  Making sure that all instances of VS2012 are closed, uninstall Windows Azure Authoring Tools, Emulator, Libraries, and Tools for v2.1, then re-install from MS Web Platform Installer.